# Как параллельно выполнять функции на C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

При запросе пользователя я хочу произвести несколько запросов к БД и потом вывести ответ.
Но, если я использую

```
async
await- Function1    
await- Function2  
await- Function3  
"склеить ответ функций и перевести в json"  
вывести ответ....
```

то фактически эти функции выполняются друг за другом с тем лишь отличием, что процесс не подвисает, пока ответа нет, в отличии от синхронного программирования, но никакой многопоточности нет.
Как сделать многопоточность и вот когда ответ будет получен со всех функций- вызвать await?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробуйте через `Task.WhenAll`:

```
Task first  = Function1();
Task second = Function2();
Task third  = Function3();

await Task.WhenAll(first, second, third);
```

Comment: Добавьте может, что результаты можно получить как `first.Result` и тд

Answer (score 3):

Для параллельного выполнения асинхронных функций нужно воспользоваться методом [`Task.WhenAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var fooTask = FooAsync();
var barTask = BarAsync();
var gazTask = GazAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(fooTask, barTask, gazTask);
```

После того, как все задачи завершатся, к результатам (если они есть) можно обратиться с помощью `await` или свойства `Result`:

```
var fooResult = await fooTask;
var barResult = barTask.Result;
var gazResult = await gazTask;
```

Стоит также упомянуть обработку исключений. Если вы не обрабатываете их в каждом из методов, то `Task.WhenAll()`, естественно, пробрасывает их наверх. Особенность заключается в том, что если `Task.WhenAll()` ожидается с помощью ключевого слова `await`, наверх выбрасывается *первое* случившееся исключение. В такой ситуации c тасками нужно обращаться аккуратнее: мы не знаем, какой из них завершился с ошибкой, а какой вообще еще не завершился. Поэтому нужны предварительные проверки с использованием свойствa `IsFaulted`/`Status`.

```
var fooTask = FooAsync();
var barTask = BarAsync();
var gazTask = GazAsync();

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(fooTask, barTask, gazTask);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (fooTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // ошибка в FooAsync()
    }
    else if (barTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // ошибка в BarAsync()
    }
    else if (gazTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // ошибка в GazAsync()
    }
}
```

Если же вы делаете блокирующее ожидание (`Task.WhenAll().Wait()`) или используете блокирующий аналог (`Task.WaitAll()`), то все произошедшие исключение помещаются внутрь `AggregateException`. Проверка, какие таски завершились ошибкой, а какие еще не завершились, остается той же.

Comment: Есть еще некий `Parallel.Invoke (Action[])`, про него можете дополнить?

Comment: @Андрей а что про него дополнять? Он предназначен для синхронных методов, а автора вопроса интересуют асинхронные методы.