# Запуск нескольких Task одновременно. Так есть ли многопоточность?

Tags: c#, async-await

В продолжение [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684868/193999) вопроса.

Итак, пусть есть несколько асинхронных методов

```
async Task DoFoo() { ... }
async Task DoBar() { ... }
async Task DoBaz() { ... }
```

которые в другом асинхронном методе

```
async Task DoJob()
{
    //TODO: perform DoFoo, DoBar and DoBaz in parallel
}
```

требуется выполнить параллельно.

Если следовать ответам в упомянутом вопросе, то для параллельности выполнения нескольких асинхронных методов нужно вызвать их так:

```
async Task DoJob()
{
    Task t1 = DoFoo();
    Task t2 = DoBar();
    Task t3 = DoBaz();

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

В документации по [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx), однако, читаю:

> Top-level tasks, which are tasks that are not created in the context
>   of another task, are put on the global queue just like any other work
>   item. However, nested or child tasks, which are created in the context
>   of another task, are handled quite differently. **A child or nested task
>   is put on a local queue that is specific to the thread on which the
>   parent task is executing.** The parent task may be a top-level task or
>   it also may be the child of another task. When this thread is ready
>   for more work, it first looks in the local queue.

Применительно к ситуации, если я правильно понимаю, задачи `t1, t2, t3` не являются задачами корневого уровня (т.к. они вложены в `DoJob`), и потому, стартуя они попадают не в *global queue*, которая обрабатывается множеством потоков пула, а - в *local queue* какого-то **одного** конкретного потока.

Получается, что многопоточного исполнения нескольких асинхронных методов такой способ не даёт?

Да, может произойти *work stealing*, но стоит ли на него надеяться, или для достижения параллелизма лучше все методы обернуть в `Task.Run(...)` (который отправит задачи исполняться на пуле потоков, т.е., по-видимому, в *global queue*)

```
async Task DoJob()
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(DoFoo);
    Task t2 = Task.Run(DoBar);
    Task t3 = Task.Run(DoBaz);

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

?

Answer (score 10):

Прям вот жирным выделю:

**Асинхронность != многопоточность. Таски != многопоточность.**

Во-первых, многопоточности тут может не быть, если все методы возвращают готовые таски.

Во-вторых, все преимущество асинхронных методов в том, что во время IO-запроса поток не блокируется и что IO-запросы могут запросто выполняться параллельно (например, потому, что это разные подсистемы вашего компьютера или разные компьютеры где-то в сети).

"Обычный" асинхронный метод состоит из некоторого синхронного пролога, одного или несколько асинхронных вызовов с синхронным кодом между ними, и синхронного эпилога. В таком методе время выполнение синхронного кода и асинхронного соотносятся как, например, 1 к 100 (потому что IO медленный, очень медленный).

Т.о., запуская параллельно N асинхронных методов, вы экономите на обращении к IO. В первую очередь именно IO-запросы будут выполняться параллельно. А тот факт, что одна копейка синхронного кода в этих методах может выполниться в одном потоке, вас не должен волновать.

Так что да, параллельно запущенные асинхронные методы могут выполняться и без использования дополнительных потоков, но такое выполнение по-прежнему имеет смысл. Особенно в том случае, когда эти методы являются настоящими асинхронным методами.

По теме:

- [Нет никакого потока](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/)
- [Как работает async/await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/106)
- [async/await: собираем грабли](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA)

Comment: Ну и надо еще добавить, что `nested or child tasks` - это совсем другой механизм, не связанный с приведенным автором кодом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `Task t1 = DoFoo();` разве не порождает detached child task?

Comment: @andreycha, В вопросе я вроде бы не уравнивал вещи, выделенные `!=`. Единственное, что кажется я уравнял - это многопоточность и параллельность, но таково положение вещей и в исходном вопросе.

Comment: @i-one в первую очередь речь идет об асинхронности. В таком случае вообще не нужно ничего сравнивать с многопоточностью. А параллельная она или последовательная, это неважно.

Comment: @i-one нет, это совершенно другой тип задачи. К примеру, такую задачу вы никогда не "поймаете" через `Task.CurrentId`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а чему, кстати, эквивалентно `Task t1 = DoFoo();`, это как-то представимо через `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` или `var t = new Task(...); t.Start();`?

Comment: @i-one нет, это работает через [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хорошо, но в итоге задачи, порождённые таким способом, исполняются на `TaskScheduler.Default` или как-то иначе? Из описания класса TaskScheduler сложилось именно такое впечателние. И даже если `Task t1 = DoFoo();` нельзя назвать child, очень похоже, однако, что процитированное имеет место быть, t1, t2, t3 попадают по-видимому именно в local queue, т.е. имеет место быть однопоточное последовательное либо квазипараллельное (одним потоком) исполнение методов.

Comment: _"Т.о., запуская параллельно N асинхронных методов..."_ так в том то и дело, что исходная конструкция, по-видимому, не запускает асинхронные методы параллельно. Например, если второй метод содержит в своём прологе cpu-intensive часть, то третий метод не стартует, пока она не исполнится. Мой вопрос как раз в большей степени про параллельность/многопоточность, чем про асинхронность.

Comment: @i-one задачи порожденные таким методом исполняются там где вы их исполняете

Comment: @i-one нет никакого `TaskScheduler.Default`, забудьте про него. *"t1, t2, t3 попадают по-видимому именно в local queue"* - нет, не попадают.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73065/discussion-between-i-one-and-pavel-mayorov).